# How to correctly use git send-email with GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, patch, git-send-email

I am going to be managing a repository hosted in gitlab soon. 
So far I have been a contributor to other repos and usually what I did was to create my own branch locally, work on that and then push my work to have a merge-request that the repo manager handled. 
I know the concept of patches but never used them extensively. 
If I want people to contribute to the repository I manage by using patches I suppose contributors will make the patches with `git format-patch` but then when they want to send them through `git send-email` how should they do it?

Do I as a gitlab repo manager get a "gitlab e-mail" to which direct the patches? or is that completely separated and I should use any generic e-mail address?  (btw, how does this-in contrast- work in github just out of curiosity)

Comment: Do you mean the repository will be hosted on gitlab.com, or on a private Gitlab install? Because if it's on gitlab.com, I would assume contributions would come in via merge requests, not e-mails.

Comment: Yes, as I said I have done in the past. Yes, it is a private Gitlab, but because this and *other* reasons, it has been decided to use patches. That is why I am asking about patches and not merge requests

Answer (score 1):

`git send-email` is [not supported yet](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25040).

You need to send an email where the subject line will become the issue title and the body will become the description. Attach your changes as a `.patch` file.

More information can be found in the documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html